# Error trying to use the function rbern in [R]

Tags: r, statistics, probability-theory

I'm trying to use rbern function in R, but it says the following message

```
rbern (10, 0.1)
Error: Could not find the "rbern"
```

I even tried to load the library (Rlab) and will not let me, I'm doing wrong?. I remember a few days use the same function smoothly. Please I need help with this.

```
library(Rlab)
Error en library(Rlab) : there is no package called ‘Rlab’
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`install.packages('Rlab')` will help

Comment: And it appears that `rbern` is just calling the base function `rbinom` anyway, so....yeah.

Comment: You're right, I finally found it more convenient to use rbin with size 1, which is a Bernoulli-type experiment

Answer (score 0):

An `rbern` is also available in the `extraDistr` package.